# How to iterate to the next sibling xml element?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Consider you have the following xml structure:

```
<root>
  <File> a.txt 
      <Version> 1.5 </Version>
  </File>

  <File> b.txt 
      <Version> 1.0 </Version>
  </File>
</root>
```

If I hold a variable which holds the element :

```
<File> a.txt 
          <Version> 1.5 </Version>
</File>
```

How can I get a handle to the next element which is:

```
<File> b.txt 
      <Version> 1.0 </Version>
</File>
```

I've been trying couple of things such as `XElement.nextNode()` but got null instead of a reasonable handle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`ElementsAfterSelf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb354563.aspx):

```
var nextElement = currentElement.ElementsAfterSelf("File").FirstOrDefault();
if (nextElement != null)
{
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, try to refactor your code so that you can use a loop over all the elements to start with:

```
foreach (var fileElement in parentElement.Elements("File"))
{
    ...
}
```

(In both cases you can omit the element name if you want just the next element, whatever it is.)

Comment: Thanks ,by the way how can I get a handle to xml element such as <Version> 1.5 </Version> and do that by searching the value 1.5?
I saw that there is similar function which search by element name: `XElement.Element(XName)`

Comment: @JavaSa: Something like: `element.Descendants("Version").FirstOrDefault(x => (decimal) x == 1.5m)`

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, the XML structure you provided here is not correct or standard structure. I may be wrong but this should be like :

```
<root>
  <File>
      <Name>a.txt</Name>
      <Version>1.5</Version>
  </File>

  <File>
      <Name>b.txt</Name> 
      <Version>1.0</Version>
  </File>
</root>
```

Now you can easily trace the value of tag Name&Version using Lambda expression

```
XDocument xd = XDocument.Load("XMLPath/xmlname.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> lstxe = xdoc.XPathSelectElements("//root/File");
foreach(XElement xele in lstxe )
{
// here you can get the each value
}
```